# getting file as response from a microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to write a spring boot method where i have to download the file which is being returned from another microservice.
Can anyone please tell me how can i do it.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

    public File processFile(MultipartFile uploadedFile) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
            if (!uploadedFile.isEmpty()) {
                byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();
                String fileName = uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename();
                File convertedFile = new File(uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
                uploadedFile.transferTo(convertedFile);
                OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                OkHttpClient client = builder.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType
                        .parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("file", fileName, RequestBody.create(mediaType, bytes)).build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("").post(requestBody)
                        .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
                        .addHeader("authorization", "Basic cGFkc2VsZWN0OjQwOWExZmMzZmExNTYwZjljZTYyOTQxZTU2ZDgyOGI2")
                        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache").build();
                Response response = null;
                try {
                    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new exception(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                            resource.getString("application.controller.parser.exception"), e);
                }
                if (!response.isSuccessful() || null == response) {
                    throw new exception(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                            resource.getString("application.controller.parser.exception"));
                } else {

                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me what i need to do in the else part to convert the response i am getting as a file and safe that as a file in my java code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method return type from "File" to "byte[]" and this will work.

```
    else {
        byte[] responseFile = (File)response.body().bytes();
        return responseFile;
    }
```

Comment: @DeShaun :- I am getting the below error - he method getBody() is undefined for the type Response

Comment: Can you add the imports to your example please?

Comment: i have added the import

Answer (score 0):

use the byte[] from body() to construct an inputstream. use this inputstream to write into a file. response header would let you know the the data type and define the file type accordingly

Comment: It would be perfect if you could paste corrected/added code in answer.